# Bean property 'Orgaddress' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Issue:

```
org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'Orgaddress' of bean class 
    [com.techvision.studycenter.model.Organization]: Bean property 'Orgaddress' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: 
    Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
```

**OrgController.java**

```
package com.techvision.studycenter.controller;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.techvision.studycenter.model.Organization;
import com.techvision.studycenter.service.OrgService;

@Controller
public class OrgController {

@Autowired  
private OrgService orgService;


    @RequestMapping(value="/login")
    public ModelAndView home(){
        return new ModelAndView("OrgList", "command", new Organization());

    }
    @RequestMapping(value="/saveOrg")
    public ModelAndView saveOrg(@ModelAttribute("orgnew")Organization organization)
    {
        orgService.saveOrg(organization);
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/add.html");  
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.GET)  
     public ModelAndView addEmployee(@ModelAttribute("orgnew")Organization organization, 
       BindingResult result) {  
      Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();  
      model.put("orgLists",  orgService.listOrgs());  
      return new ModelAndView("orgList", model);  
     }
}
```

**OrgService.java**

```
package com.techvision.studycenter.service;

import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import com.techvision.studycenter.model.Organization;

public interface OrgService {

    void saveOrg(Organization organization);
    List<Organization> listOrgs();

}
```

**OrgServiceImpl.java**

```
package com.techvision.studycenter.service;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.techvision.studycenter.model.Organization;
@Service("OrgService")
@Transactional
public class OrgSerivceImpl implements OrgService {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    @Override
    public void saveOrg(Organization organization) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         System.out.println("i am at service");
         sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(organization);  
    }

    @Override
    public List<Organization> listOrgs() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          return (List<Organization>) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Organization.class).list();  

    }

}
```

**JPA entities**

**Organization.java**

```
package com.techvision.studycenter.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Date;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Set;


/**
 * The persistent class for the organization database table.
 * 
 */
@Entity
@Table(name="organization")
@NamedQuery(name="Organization.findAll", query="SELECT o FROM Organization o")
public class Organization implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(unique=true, nullable=false)
    private long orgid;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date dateofcreation;

    @Column(length=45)
    private String orgcode;

    @Column(length=45)
    private String orgmode;

    @Column(length=45)
    private String orgname;

    private long orgparent;

    @Column(length=1)
    private char orgstatus;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Degreecategory
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="organization")
    private Set<Degreecategory> degreecategories;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Medium
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="organization")
    private Set<Medium> mediums;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Orgaddress
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="organization")
    private Set<Orgaddress> orgaddresses;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Person
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="organization")
    private Set<Person> persons;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Yearname
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="organization")
    private Set<Yearname> yearnames;

    public Organization() {
    }
//getter and setter methods...
}
```

**OrgAddress.java**

```
package com.techvision.studycenter.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Date;


/**
 * The persistent class for the orgaddress database table.
 * 
 */
@Entity
@Table(name="orgaddress")
@NamedQuery(name="Orgaddress.findAll", query="SELECT o FROM Orgaddress o")
public class Orgaddress implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(unique=true, nullable=false)
    private long orgaddressid;

    @Column(length=100)
    private String address1;

    @Column(length=100)
    private String address2;

    @Column(length=100)
    private String city;

    @Column(length=45)
    private String country;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date dateofcreation;

    @Column(length=200)
    private String emailid1;

    @Column(length=200)
    private String emailid2;

    @Column(length=45)
    private String fax;

    @Column(length=45)
    private String landlinenumber;

    @Column(length=100)
    private String location;

    @Column(length=45)
    private String mobilenumber;

    @Column(length=45)
    private String orgaddresscol;

    @Column(length=1)
    private char orgaddressstatus;

    @Column(length=45)
    private String postalcode;

    @Column(length=45)
    private String state;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Organization
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="orgid", nullable=false)
    private Organization organization;

    public Orgaddress() {
    }
//getter and setter method...
}
```

**OrgList.jsp**

```
 <form:input path="orgcode" id="orgcode" name="orgcode" type="text" placeholder="Org Code" class="form-control input-md"/>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Street1</label>  
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <form:input path="Orgaddress.address1" id="Orgaddress.address1" type="text" placeholder="placeholder" class="form-control input-md"/>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Street 2</label>  
  <div class="col-md-4">
 <form:input path="Orgaddress.address2" id="Orgaddress.address2" name="Orgaddress.address2" type="text" placeholder="placeholder" class="form-control input-md"/>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">City</label>  
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <form:input path="orgaddresses.city" id="orgaddresses.city" name="city" type="text" placeholder="placeholder" class="form-control input-md"/>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Country</label>  
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <form:input path="orgaddresses.country" id="orgaddresses.country" name="orgaddressescountry" type="text" placeholder="placeholder" class="form-control input-md"/>

  </div>
</div>
<!-- Button -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="singlebutton">Single Button</label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <button id="singlebutton" name="singlebutton" class="btn btn-primary">Button</button>
  </div>
</div>
</fieldset>
</form:form>
```

**spring-servlet.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"

    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd">

        <!-- <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:resources/database.properties">  </context:property-placeholder> -->
        <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:resources/database.properties"/>

    <!-- It register the beans in context and scan the annotations inside beans and activate them -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.techvision.studycenter" />

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/mytheme/" />

    <!-- This allow for dispatching requests to Controllers by registering 
     two beans - DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping and AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <!-- This helps in mapping the logical view names to directly view files under a certain pre-configured directory -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <!-- This resolves messages from resource bundles for different locales --> 
 <!--    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="messages" />
    </bean> -->

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="hibernateTransactionManager"/>  


<bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" id="dataSource">  
 <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}"></property>  
 <property name="url" value="${database.url}"></property>  
 <property name="username" value="${database.user}"></property>  
 <property name="password" value="${database.password}"></property>  
</bean>  

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean" id="sessionFactory">  
 <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>  
 <property name="annotatedClasses">  
  <list>  

    <value>com.techvision.studycenter.model.Orgaddress</value>
    <value>com.techvision.studycenter.model.Organization</value>
 </list>  
 </property>  
 <property name="hibernateProperties">  
 <props>  
  <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>  
  <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>  
  <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}  </prop>      
    </props>  
      </property>  
</bean>  

  <bean class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager" id="hibernateTransactionManager">  
 <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>  
  </bean>  
   </beans>
```

Comment: You posted a wall of code, but didn't post the only relevant part: the getters and setters in Organization. Read the exception message: that's what it complains about.

Comment: Here's an exception, here's *all the code* doesn't really seem like you've put enough effort into this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your organization model

```
        public String getPrivacyname()
        {
            String address1=null;
            if (orgaddresses != null ) 
            {
                 List<Orgaddress> orgAddresses= new ArrayList(getOrgaddresses());
                if(orgAddresses!=null)
                {
                    for(Orgaddress OrgAddress : orgAddresses){
                        address1= OrgAddress.getAddress1();
                    }
                }

            }
            return address1;


          }
```